# JSON array into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to convert json array

```
                {"id":"1","name":"abc"},
                {"id":"2","name":"pqr"},
                {"id":"3","name":"xyz"};
```

into this kind of js array

```
 var locations = [
    [1, 'abc'],
    [2, 'pqr'],
    [3, 'xyz']
];
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: As written, that's not a JSON array--I assume that's a typo. Which part is causing you a problem?

Comment: by using this location array i am trying to create multiple markers on google map

Comment: What you are calling a "json array" is neither JSON nor an array. Is that text in a string? Is it the (text) response from an Ajax call? Is it perhaps supposed to be a JS array of objects? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the elements objects, (and not as Json as you state):

```
var data = [{"id":"1","name":"abc"},
            {"id":"2","name":"pqr"},
            {"id":"3","name":"xyz"}];
```

You can the convert it to a two-dimensional array like this

```
var output = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output[i] = new Array(data[i].id, data[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Actually i get this json array by using this   var javaArray = <?php echo json_encode($result['result']) ?>;

Comment: in any case, try the code posted. - just add "var data=" in front of the code generated by PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this.

```
var jsondata=[{"id":"1","name":"abc"},
                {"id":"2","name":"pqr"},
                {"id":"3","name":"xyz"}];
var arrayObj=$.parseJSON(jsondata);
```

Comment: Your `jsondata` variable is not a string, so won't work with `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: i got the solution thanks to all

var locations = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    locations[i] = new Array(javaArray[i].id,javaArray[i].name);
  
}